# Change background image of website with select tag

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I am learning JavaScript and I managed to change the background color:

```
<script>
     function changecolor(id,color) {
            id.style.backgroundColor=color;
     }
</script>


<div id="container">
     <p> Select Color to change background:</p>
     <select id="themenu" onchange="changecolor(container,themenu.value)">
          <option value="white"> </option>
          <option value="red">RED</option>
          <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
          <option value="green">GREEN</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

is there any other method to do it?

Comment: You should definately take a look at jQuery (http://www.jquery.com/). jQuery is a JavaScript library that does these kind of things along with animations, verifications and much more a whole bit easier!

Comment: @Tom As he mentioned, he is just learning JavaScript and not jQuery. Let's show him a bit of pure JavaScript before jumping head first into jQuery hell shall we?

Comment: i am finding it easy JS , is jquery hard or what O.o @heartcode

Comment: @Katyoshah JS is easy and that's why I think it's better for newbies to start with vanilla JS instead of a popular and robust library to solve simple problems.

Answer (score 4):

You might just got stuck in the syntaxes

```
<select id="themenu" onchange="changecolor(container,this.value)"> <!-- Change -->
 <option value="white"> </option>
 <option value="red">RED</option>
 <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
 <option value="green">GREEN</option>
</select>
```

`this.value` refers to the current object's selected value!

`themenu.value` also works fine you might just got stuck somewhere else!

[**Demo Update**](http://jsfiddle.net/8v6Yy/1/)

[**Another Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8v6Yy/2/)

Comment: changecolor(this? but i want to change the color of the div container

Answer (score 3):

I just called the parent element and its working perfectly.

```
onchange="changecolor(this.parentNode,themenu.value)"
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tonyjose009/8v6Yy/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript function should be this;

```
function changecolor(id,color){
  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor=color;
}
```

Comment: do i have to add document.getElementByid(id) why not directly id.style ? @brokenheart

Comment: @Katyoshah because of `container` is the id of the html element. so you need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply refer to the current object (this), and then to it's parent node and it's value instead of using ids :

```
<script>
    function useValueAsParentColor(menu) {
        menu.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = menu.value;
    }
</script>

<div>
    <p> Select Color to change background:</p>
    <select onchange="useValueAsParentColor(this); ">
        <option value="white"> </option>
        <option value="red">RED</option>
        <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
        <option value="green">GREEN</option>
    </select>
</div>
```